# Where does WooCommerce store settings in database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have looked in the database tables, especially all the ones prefixed by wp_woocommerce as well as the wp_options table.

I can't seem to find where the configuration settings are storeed.

Comment: Found the answer so edited question for clarity and to make me look less stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Orders are setup as Posts (custom post_type). So the ID assigned to each order varies on the wp_posts table's AutoIncrement value of 'ID'.

You can modify its value if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

This is stored in the

```
wp-options
```

table beginning with woocommerce_default_country

Comment: The correct name is table wp_options. So much time has to be.

Answer (score 1):

In the options table, you have something like `woocommerce_{ the gateway id }_settings`. The data is tore in an array of sort.

You did not answer the question when you found the answer. I had similar challenge. I figured it out.